# Are there Taylor series for functions of a matrix?

Tags: calculus, analysis, matrices

Say you have a scalar function $f(x,A)$ of a vector $x$ and a matrix $A$. Does there exist a Taylor series of sorts for the matrix $A$? I was thinking naively that this would simply be of the form $\sum_{n} \frac{\partial^{n}f(x,0)}{\partial A^{n}}\frac{A^{n}}{n!}$ Where the derivatives are taken with respect to the matrix $A$. The sum should still be a scalar so that the powers of $A$ match with the derivatives taken with respect to $A$, so that all indices are summed over implicitly. Any suggestions or comments?

Comment: I think you need to give an example of sort of function you have in mind. Your series appears as something that gives a matrix as in Shu's answer below. But you say you are looking for  a scalar function.

Comment: Pretend it's a function of an inner product of two vectors with regard to some matrix A. The inner product is clearly a scalar and thus the function will be, but how would you go about expanding it in terms of the matrix?

Comment: Yes, the space of $n\times m$ matrices over $K=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$ can be identified with $K^{nm}$. And [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) generalize to functions of several variables.

Comment: Thanks julien, but could you be a little more specific? I'm not sure you're thinking of the same ideas I am. I know that you can write down a Taylor series for a multivariate function, but I'm curious if there is a matrix analog such that each derivative is a matrix derivative, and each 'polynomial' power is a matrix power. Essentially expanding a scalar function of a matrix into powers of the matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a $k$-variable smooth function we have the following form for Taylor's theorem $$f(x+h)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  {{(h\cdot \nabla)^n}\over{n!}}f(x)$$ where \begin{align}x&=(x_1,\cdots,x_k)\\ h&=(h_1,\cdots,h_k)\\ \nabla&=\left({\partial \over \partial x_1},\cdots,{\partial \over \partial x_k}\right)\;.\end{align}

If $g$ is a smooth scalar function, $X,H$ matrices, $A,B$ column vectors, so that $A^TXB$ is a dot product through $X$, then I believe the above leads to

$$g(A^T(X+H)B)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {{(A^T HB)^n}\over {n!}}g^{(n)}(A^TXB)$$

Comment: Sorry, what does "...$A^TXB$ is a dot product through $X$" mean?

Comment: @ali To get a scalar from X, like dot product we get a scalar.