# Non-commutative matrix Taylor series + How to compute the Jordan Chevalley

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, matrix-exponential

I have some matrix $J$, which has a decomposition into the diagonal matrix $D$, and the nilpotent matrix $N$. It is *almost* exactly like a Jordan block, except with ones on the subdiagonal even when the $\lambda$ on the diagonal change - plus, it's transposed. I.e, $J,D,N$ look like this:

$$J=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\1&\lambda_2&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&1&\lambda_3&0&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&0\\0&0&0&\cdots&\lambda_{n-1}&0\\0&0&0&\cdots&1&\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}D=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&\lambda_2&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&\lambda_3&0&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&0\\0&0&0&\cdots&\lambda_{n-1}&0\\0&0&0&\cdots&0&\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}N=J-D$$

The Taylor series (incidentally the function is $\exp(tJ$) I am centering around $tD$:

$$f(tJ)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(tD)}{k!}\cdot (tJ-tD)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(tD)}{k!}\cdot (tN)^k$$

But the order of the multiplication $f^{(k)}(tD)\times (tN)^k$ is extremely important, since $N,D$ don't commute. Which way is correct, rigorously, and why? It seems to me that the extension of the Taylor series to matrix functions requires some extra thought!

Edit - perhaps it is a requirement on Taylor series that the two summands commute? Is this the case, meaning I must split $tJ$ some other, commutative, way? I know the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition states that such a commutative split exists, but I've seen nothing about how one actually finds $J=S+N:SN=NS%$.

Comment: The Jordan decomposition is more of a theoretical tool. Using it for numerical computations is a bad idea.

Comment: In this case specifically it would be useful to me - probably anyway, I assume a matrix as simple as mine has an acceptable form. The Taylor series question still stands though, @greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\p{\partial}
\def\A{{\cal A}}\def\B{{\cal B}}\def\C{{\cal C}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\LR{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}\bigg|_{#3}}}
$Taylor series with matrix variables do not work the way you think they do.

For example, consider the second-order series of $f(X)$ centered at $X_0$
$$\eqalign{
f(X) &= \frac1{0!}f(X_0) \\
  &+\; \frac1{1!}\LR{X-X_0}:\hess{f}{X}{X=X_0} \\
  &+\; \frac1{2!}\LR{X-X_0}\star\LR{X-X_0}:\,:\hess{^2f}{X^2}{X=X_0} \\
}$$
In this expansion,  $(:,\, :\,:)$ denote the double and *quadruple* contraction products, $(\star)$ denotes the dyadic (aka tensor) product, and the terms in parentheses are second and fourth order tensors.

In general, the $n^{th}$ order Taylor series of a function of $m^{th}$ order tensors will involve tensors and contraction products of order $mn$.

The Taylor series as derived in undergraduate calculus is only possible because scalars are $0^{th}$ order tensors, i.e. $\;m=0$.

Comment: Right... Do you have a reference for this? I can appreciate the (very stong) intuition behind Taylor's theorem, but I would be interested in seeing a proof / link to a proof of the Taylor series for matrices. I appreciate the comment about the $n$th derivatives being $2^n$ order tensors, that has made me realise a key difference between the typical Taylor and matrix Taylor series... I wonder if your statement can show the result on Wikipedia's page, that a matrix function of a Jordan block is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function_of_a_matrix#Jordan_decomposition)

Comment: I proved it to myself using what I thought was a valid Taylor expansion, but maybe the genuinely valid Taylor expansion proves it too. I would do this myself, but I'm unfamiliar with this term "contraction product"

Comment: $\def\dss{\mathop{\bullet}\limits}\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}$Here's an example of a triple contraction product between a 4th & 5th order tensor
$$\eqalign{
C &= A \dss^3 B \\
C_{imn} &= \sum_{\c{j}=1}^J\sum_{\c{k}=1}^K\sum_{\c{\ell}=1}^L A_{i\c{jk\ell}} B_{\c{jk\ell}mn} \\
}$$
And here's an example of a dyadic product between the same tensors
$$\eqalign{
F &= A \star B \\
F_{ijk\ell pqrmn} &= A_{ijk\ell} B_{pqr mn} \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you. What is the definition of the order of contraction? Can you take an $k$th order product on two tensors of order $m,n$ where $k\lt m\le n$?

Comment: The _rightmost_ indices of the tensor on the LHS are contracted with the _leftmost_ indices of the tensor on the RHS (in the same order).  The number of indices involved is the order of the contraction product, which cannot exceed the order of the lesser order tensor.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are you aware of an extension of Taylor's theorem using tensors and contractions? Aware of a proof, that is

Comment: No, but you can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation)

Comment: How does your Taylor series corroborate [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/332543/815585) answer?

Comment: That answer only applies to the case that $x$ is a vector in ${\mathbb R}^{k}\,$ and all of "ugliness" is lurking inside of the term $(h\cdot\nabla)^n\;$